# Why does CSS 3d animations work on safari and not chrome if they are both build using webkit?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I was wondering why the CSS 3d animation work on safari (desktop/ipad/iphone) browser but not on latest chrome 9.0. Aren't chrome and safari both based on the webkit platform???

Also, how can I stay in the loop with Chrome (desktop/android) browser and their plans to support CSS 3d in the future?

Link is here: http://girliemac.com/sandbox/flickr_3d.html

Thanks.

EDIT: For those of you who says it works on Chrome, can you please try it on safari? It looks like it works on Chrome but it REALLy works on the latest safari or get the nightly build.

Comment: It seems to work in my chrome... not firefox, though

Comment: Works in my chrome too, build 9.0.597.98 running on ubuntu.

Comment: Works in my chrome, a little slow and the bottom scrollbar goes REALLLY deep, but other than that, it's fine

Comment: Works in my chrome too, build 9.0.597.98, windows 7 x64

Comment: Much like the others works _fine_ in my chrome (8.0.552.237 on XP). Bit slow though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use chrome 9.0.597.107; chrome disable 3d animation by default.
so, if want enable it, just open a new tab, access the page : about:flags
In that page, make sure enable the GPU.
restart the chrome , then you should see the 3d animation .

Comment: Thanks! It works but is much less smooth than it runs on the safari. The animation is like bouncing up and down instead of a smooth controlled flow. Still though, ur answer nailed it.